# Target of event when the child fill up the parent container

Tags: javascript

In the following example, is it possible the `event.target` be the parent element?

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.addEventListener("click", click);

function click(event) {
  alert(event.target.id);
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can retrieve the element the event was bound to using `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: I am aware of that. I wanted to know if technically it may happen.

Comment: In old IEs it was possible to hit the parent under a child if the child had transparent backgroundcolor, but modern browsers can't "see" through elements.

Comment: You are adding the `addEventListener` to the parent, so there are various ways you might be able to "dodge" the child and hit the parent (with different CSS/when the parent contains other elements/is focusable), but none of those appear in your example. What exactly are you trying to achieve/learn, with some more context we may be able to give more useful answers.

Comment: @DBS I really liked the use of word "dodge" in your comment. I am building a carousel and want the user be able to swipe by mouse. But there are other elements in there too. So I want to swipe only if the target is an image which fill ups its container.